# stringWithCString:encoding: returned nil, when the input cstring contains emoji

Tags: ios, c, nsstring, null, emoji

Here is the story.
I'm using a C lib for data transmission, and all work well except for certain Emoji.
For the receiver, the received message is **char *message**, for which can use "**printf**" to print out the right thing. but when using **stringWithCString:encoding:**(or **stringWithUTF8String:** etc.), it return nil for certain emoji.

So, I print out each char, and here the successful emoji:

**"\xe2\x9a\xbd"**

**"\xe2\x9a\xbe\xef\xb8\x8f"**

**"\xe2\x98\x81\xef\xb8\x8f"**

But the failed emoji:

**"\xed\xa0\xbc\xed\xbe\x82"**

**"\xed\xa0\xbc\xed\xbf\x80"**

**"\xed\xa0\xbc\xed\xbc\x88"**

have beening stuck on this days.

any ideas?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your bytes are not a valid UTF-8 encoded string. According to [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), "\xed\xa0\xbc" encodes the Unicode code point U+D83C. This is a code point in the high surrogate block. Surrogates are not valid characters and are reserved for UTF-16 purposes. It is not valid for UTF-8 to encode such codepoints.

Comment: @Edward: No, the encoding is irrelevant. The same problem will occur if you have an incorrectly-encoded data with any encoding. The issue is where are you getting these bytes in the first place; you are encoding something in the wrong way.

Comment: @newacct These are CESU-8 / Modified UTF-8 sequences where UTF-16 surrogates are encoded in UTF-8.